# Query records with nested relationships 2-levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 models [Project, Task, TaskAssignment, User] with this relationsships:

- Tasks `n:m` Users `through` TaskAssignment
- Projects `hasMany` Tasks

Now I want to get all projects that have tasks that are assigned to a specific user.

My attempt:

```
Project
    .includes(:tasks, {:task_assignments => [:tasks, :task_assignments]})
    .where("task_assignments.user_id = #{user_id}")
    .references(:tasks)
```

Throws `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Association named 'task_assignment' was not found on Project; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

First, add this relationship to the Project model:

```
has_many :task_assignments, through: :tasks
```

Then use this query:

```
Project.includes(:task_assignments).where("task_assignments.user_id = #{user_id}").references(:task_assignments)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using joins for this, anyways task_assignments belong to task. try working it like that.